# Windows Ink in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

Can use Windows Ink on Windows 10 Mobile? Can I published an uwp app with Windows Ink for Windows 10 Mobile?
Or Windows Ink only Works in Windows 10 Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

> Can use Windows Ink on Windows 10 Mobile?

If you mean you are using the [`InkCanvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas) control in a UWP app, and you want to know if the `InkCanvas` can work when running this UWP app on a Windows 10 mobile device, in that case, the short answer should be yes. `InkCanvas` is not only work for desktop devices.

But pay attention that you must specify support for other devices through the [`InputDeviceTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpresenter#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkPresenter_InputDeviceTypes) of an `InkPresenter` object. For mobile you may need to add the `Touch` device type.

> Can I published an uwp app with Windows Ink for Windows 10 Mobile

You could publish it to windows store, and install it in your mobile. There is no special capabilities needed for this control.